# How to reset only system configuration of QNAP TS-119

Tags: nas

I'm not sure if this is correct place to ask though...

My QNAP TS-119 got problem.

After updating the firmware, it doesn't start. - Blinking `STATUS` with red LED and `ping` doesn't respond anymore.
I removed the HDD and then the NAS worked. I checked the HDD with USB connection on OSX and could see the contents. So I guess the problem is the configuration partition in my HDD.

Is there any way to reset only configuration partition in my HDD?